# Rails javascript becomes one line

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript

Javascript and coffeescript files in my Rails app are rendered with proper spacing and indentation on my local server. However, once deployed to a remote server, they render as a single line with variable names changed to single-characters, seemingly in an attempt to "scramble" the javascript. What is causing this? How can I turn this behavior off?

For context, I'm trying to debug a javascript file in my Rails app for IE9, for which I use Virtual Box to view the staging version of the app. While I guess I'd prefer "scrambled" javascript on production, its very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done by the asset pipeline of which you can read more about [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

If you want to turn it off just add this to your *config/application.rb*

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd been looking for that one line for awhile